# Gails - Hazelcast IllegalStateException on application stop

Tags: grails, hazelcast, session-replication

I'm trying some way to clusterize my grails application, I've found Hazelcast very interesting.

I made a little test application to try the integration with grails.

I followed the documentation on the site, to make the session replication.

I found that when I stop a node it starts to throw a lot of exception like this:

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.hazelcast.cluster.AddOrRemoveConnection.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1597)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.NodeIOService.removeEndpoint(NodeIOService.java:108)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ConnectionMonitor.onError(ConnectionMonitor.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ConnectionManager.failedConnection(ConnectionManager.java:255)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector.run(SocketConnector.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:909)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Exception in thread "pool-11-thread-18" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/cluster/AddOrRemoveConnection
    at com.hazelcast.nio.NodeIOService.removeEndpoint(NodeIOService.java:108)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ConnectionMonitor.onError(ConnectionMonitor.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.ConnectionManager.failedConnection(ConnectionManager.java:254)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.SocketConnector.run(SocketConnector.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can anyone explain me why it happens and how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: What version of Grails and Hazelcast are you using? Can you show some code?